# How to connect API in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I and my team are working in Reactjs and I'm completely new to this my part is Connect to API and I follow many resources on the internet, and I don't know that am I on the right track here the code that I did, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? This part is on the client I want to connect API to the server.I've recieved error:Unexpected reserved word 'await'

````
  useEffect(()=>{
    try {
      const requestUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/';
      const response = await fetch(requestUrl);
      const requestJSON = await response.json();
      console.log({responseJSON});
      const {data} = responseJSON;
      setPostEvent(data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Failed to fetch post list: ',error.message);
    }
    fetchPostEvent()
  },[events])
  useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem('events',JSON.stringify(events));
  },[events]) ```
````

Comment: First things first, you should read about [async/await syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: Then, depending on how fluent you are in React, give [this deep dive into useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) a read.

Comment: please read basic documentation  of nodejs and reactjs after that write code is always better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are to use await key word, in an async function. This is how you would make your function async:

```
  useEffect(async()=>{
    try {
      const requestUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/';
      const response = await fetch(requestUrl);
      const requestJSON = await response.json();
      console.log({responseJSON});
      const {data} = responseJSON;
      setPostEvent(data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Failed to fetch post list: ',error.message);
    }
    fetchPostEvent()
  },[events])
```